# Trouble with scopes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the following :

```js
var myVariable = {};

function() {
  //Add key/value to myVariable
}

//Using the keys/values of myVariable;
```

But it seems the keys/values are only accessible inside the function scope.
What should I do in order to modify a variable inside a function and be able to use it outside of this function ? Is it mandatory to use a global variable ?

EDIT : Changing the declaration from myVariable = [] to {} solved the issue. There was a syntax error between the declaration and the use of keys/values.

Comment: You can't add key value in array. You should use a literally object : `{}`

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Your code has syntax errors in it (and has vague comments instead of a demonstration of the problem). Your variable is already global.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut — Array indexes are keys (and arrays are objects so can have arbitrary properties added to them, although it usually isn't a good idea to do that).

Comment: Thanks for your help, correcting the syntax error solved the issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all your code contains some syntax errors.
You can change the value of `myVariable` inside function because here it is a global variable and accessible to the function.

The problem you are facing may be with the place where you are calling the function.

```js
var myVariable = {};

function changeMyVariable() {
  myVariable.mykey = 'xyz';
}

console.log(myVariable);//before calling function
changeMyVariable();
console.log(myVariable);//after calling function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the main issue was my syntax errors, I declared it as an array and tried to add keys/values. Changing the declaration from [] to {} solved the issue

Answer (score -2):

```
var myArray = []; // Global empty array.

function myFunction() {
  myArray.push({aKey:"aValue"}); // Add a key and a value to the array.
  console.log(myArray); // Print the array in the console.
}

myFunction(); // Call the function, otherwise nothing will happen.
```

Comment: A syntax error made the whole snippet not working, it is good now, thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

Can you please add an example of what you want to accomplish?
What you're explaining in your question is right and is the way the scopes works in javascript.

For instance:

```js
var myVariable = [];

console.log(myVariable); // length = 0

function updateVar() {
  myVariable[0] = 1;//Add key/value to myVariable
} 

updateVar(); // call update

console.log(myVariable);  // length = 1
```

As you can see after calling the updateVar function, you have 1 item in your array.

Comment: A syntax error made the whole snippet not working, it is good now, thanks for your help